# How to prove the well-Definedness of the Operation $.\:$?

Tags: formal-languages

Let $L\subseteq  \Sigma^*$ a Language

$R_L$ is the Myhill-Nerode-Relation of $L$

$\equiv_L$ is the Syntactic Congruence of $L$

$R_L$ and $\equiv_L$ are equivalence relations and are defined as follows :

$x\:R_L\:y \:\Leftrightarrow \: [\forall w\in\Sigma^* : xw\in L\Leftrightarrow yw\in L] $

$u\:\equiv_L\:v \:\Leftrightarrow \: [\forall x,y\in\Sigma^* : xuy\in L\Leftrightarrow xvy\in L] $

How to prove that the operation $"."$ (which i guess is the Concatenation) on the equivalent classes of $R_L$ and $\equiv_L$ is well defined ?

a) $[u_1]_{R_L} . [u_2]_{R_L} = [u_1u_2]_{R_L}$

b) $[u_1]_{\equiv_L} . [u_2]_{\equiv_L} = [u_1u_2]_{\equiv_L}$